# Android - Going from Binders to Broadcasts

Tags: android, service

I started with a standard local android service, and used Binders with Listeners to communicate. Then: I began noticing some serious issues with handling orientation changes, so I decided to skip the whole binder thing, and just go with broadcasting intents (and using startService exclusively) that contain all the data/commands that need to be passed.

My question is: what are some of the pitfalls I have to look out for when using this approach?

Are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supporting API Level 4 and above, use `setPackage()` to make your "broadcast" be a "narrowcast" -- keeping the broadcast within your app. By default, the broadcast is truly broadcast, to all apps, which may or may not be a good thing for your data.

Don't forget to unregister your `BroadcastReceiver` (i.e., don't register it and forget it). At the same time, you will need to consider what to do if the service wraps up and the activity is long gone (e.g., BACK button). One approach is to use an ordered broadcast with a low-priority manifest-registered receiver that will raise a `Notification` if no activity handles the broadcast -- [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered) demonstrates what I mean.

You might consider a `Messenger` instead of the broadcast approach, as it is intrinsically a "narrowcast", probably is a smidge less overhead, and can't be leaked. I am still working through the mechanics of using this with configuration changes, though.

Comment: "Can't be leaked" - how could my method leak?

Comment: @Joseph: If you register a `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()` and do not unregister it, I am uncertain if it will be automatically cleared out for you. You can definitely leak `LocationListener` and `SensorEventListener` this way.